# How to compare 2 dictionaries?

Tags: python, if-statement, for-loop, dictionary, compare

I am inputting one dictionary which may be like:

```
myWorld = {'MH': {'Mumbai': 1, 'Pune': 2}, 'GUJ': 3, 'RSA': {} }
```

and my test dictionary is :

```
World = {'MH': {'Mumbai': 1, 'Pune': 2}, 'GUJ': 3, 'RSA': {}, 'USA': 4, 'UK': 5 }
```

I want to check a condition such that if anything I enter in `myWorld` is not present in `World`, it should print `NotFound`

```
for key, val in myWorld.iteritems():
    if (key, val) not in (World.keys(), World.values()) in World.iteritems():
        print "NotFound"
    else:
        print "Correct"
```

This doesn't seem the right way though. As I'm getting `NotFound` for whatever the dictionary I'm inputting even though it's `"{'RSA':{}}"`. I'm new to python so don't know much about it. Can anyone tell where this is going wrong and how to fix it?

`Dictionaries = 
    {
         'A':{}'B':{}, 'C':{}, 'D':{}, 'myWorld' : {'id':1, 'name': 10},
        {'id':2, 'name': 20},
        {'id':3, 'name': 30},
        {'id':4, 'name': 40},
        {'id':5, 'name': 50}
    }`

I'm running `tests` along with `classes`.
`A, b, C, D, myWorld` are `classes` here.

I run my test like `mytest.py "{'A':{}}"`
`mytest.py "{'myWorld' : {'id':1, 'name': 10}}"`

or

`mytest.py "{'myWorld' : {'id':2, 'name': 20}}"`
Hence the argument I am entering with `mytest.py`, I'm saving it in l.
where `l = ast.literal_eval(args[0])`

Now when I dont want the unneccessary tests to run, I'm doing

```
if all(key in Dictionaries and Dictionaries[key] == key and value for key, value in  l.iteritems()):
    proceed
else:
    exit(1)
```

Now with the suggestion of if statement given here, it always becomes true and I always proceed in case of wrong combination of keys and values.
Eg even if I do `mytest.py 'myWorld' : {'id':1, 'name': 12}`

I don't want that. I want it to run only for the possibilities mentioned in `Dictionaries`

Comment: Do you want to print 'NotFound' just once if there are any number of mismatches, or once for each missing key/value pair?

Comment: do key and value have to match or just a key or a value?

Comment: I want to print not found when a key doesn't match it's respective value from `World` dictionary so it should print `Correct` when I'm inputting `{'MH': {Mumbai: 1, 'Pune': 2}}` and `NotFound` when `{'MH': {Mumbai: 99, 'Pune': 8}}`/ `{'MH': {}}`

Comment: some of your keys and values are nested, you would have to flatten to compare all the keys

Answer (score 1):

One way:

```
if all(key in World and World[key] == value for key, value in myWorld.iteritems()):
    print "Correct"
else:
    print "NotFound"
```

This uses simple equality on the values - if you need something different for, say, your nested `'Mumbai'` dict it shouldn't be too hard to adapt, just change how you compare `value`.

Comment: prints `Correct` even when input is `{'RSA': {Mumbai: 1, 'Pune': 2}}`

Comment: @pyLearner: show your test code, I think there's something wrong with it. For one thing, what are the values of the variables `Mumbai`, `Ahm`, `NY` and `London`? All of which you're using as variable names in code you've posted because you haven't put quotes around them. This code doesn't print "correct" for `World = {'MH': {'Mumbai': 1, 'Pune': 2}, 'GUJ': 'Ahm', 'RSA': {}, 'USA': 'NY
', 'UK': 'London' }` and `myWorld = {'RSA': {'Mumbai': 1, 'Pune': 2}}`, though.

Comment: @SteveJessop `{'MH': {'Mumbai': 1, 'Pune': 2}}` is JSON structure where it's also one dictionary with `key` as `MH` and `values` as `{'Mumbai': 1, 'Pune': 2}`

Comment: @SteveJessop I have edited the code. `London`, `Ahm` was confusing. Sorry for that

Comment: Given the values of `myWorld` and `World` shown above, this works - `'Correct'` for the listed `myWorld`, `'NotFound'` for `'{'RSA': {'Mumbai': 1, 'Pune': 2}}'`. If you're seeing something different, there's still something wrong with your testing code.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper I tried the same thing again. Seems like `if` always becomes `true` and it's printing `Correct` for anything. :(

Comment: Show exactly what you're testing if you want anyone to be able to help.

Comment: What you posted isn't even valid Python. Sorry, but I'm done.

Answer (score 0):

```
myWorld == World
```

this would work.

UPDATE:

```
if myWorld == World:
    print 'correct'
else:
    print 'not found'
```

Comment: @HuStmpHrr it prints `Correct` even though I input `{'MH': {}}` . It shouldn't right? I tried with various combinations. It's not working I want it to print `Correct` only when **both keys and respective values** are correct. It's printing Correct even when input is `{'MH': {Mumbai: 11, 'Pune': 12}}` So it's not comparing values.

Comment: @pyLearner this does recursive comparison and compare both keys and corresponding values. how could it not work? please specify your requirement.

Comment: @pyLearner i am confused about how you test it. in my computer `tmp = {'MH': {'Mumbai': 11, 'Pune': 12}}; tmp==World` outputs `False`

Comment: @pyLearner ok, i think i got how you test it. please see my edit.

Comment: The OP is asking to detect whether `myWorld` is a sub-dictionary of `World`, not an equal dictionary. If `World` has keys not in `myWorld` the OP still wants it to indicate `correct`. Or at least that's how I read the question.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr it's giving `Correct` irrespective of what you enter :(

Answer (score 0):

This should in principle do what you want:

```
world_items = world.items()
if all(it in world_items for it in myWorld.iteritems()):
    print 'correct'
else:
    print 'not correct'
```

Comment: Why would you use an iterative lookup on the world items?

Comment: It's printing `Correct` even when input is `{'MH': {Mumbai: 101, 'Pune': 102}}`

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper what else would you do? A set based approach wouldn't work if there are dicts within the values...

Comment: Instead of dictionary lookup, as in my answer. `(k, v) in d.items()` is slower than `k in dict and dict[k] == v`. Or, if the dictionary is sure not to contain `None`, just `dict.get(k) == v`.

Comment: Well, right, I didn't see your answer, actually. Performance wise, that's probably better..

Answer (score 0):

You can also compare dictionaries with these:

```
  notthesame_item = set(myWorld.items()) ^ set(World.items())
  print len(notthesame_item) # should be 0
```

The XOR operator (^) will eliminate all elements of the dict when they are the same in both dicts.

```
   thesame_items = set(myWorld.items()) & set(World.items())
   print len(thesame_items)
```

The matching elements from both dictionaries will be displayed.